# BackgroundImage in css

Tags: html, css

how to put **backgound image** with help of **css**.
When an image file is stored locally on a desktop, CSS file and image are in the same folder. `\Desktop\New folder\image`:- image destination
`\Desktop\New folder\css`:- css file destination

Comment: You can't tell me that Google did not help you with this ...

Answer (score 1):

You can provide just the local image name, assuming it is in the same folder and your css is applying then this should help you:

```
background-image: url("image_name.png")
```

Answer (score -1):

use `background: url()` in `css` for this

```css
body {
  background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg");
  background-size: 80px 60px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Technically, local files are not accessible from CSS. All the file you want to access should be accessible using URI.

Comment: So what is possible way to do it

Comment: put it in your server, get the URI, and put it in the URI, as shown in the solution given by @Bhargav.

Comment: Technically, local files are accessible from CSS (using relative path), while the webpage is accessed locally.